# How can I speed up parsing of large strings?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I've made a program that reads in various config files. Some of these config files can be small, some can be semi-large (largest one is 3,844 KB).

The read in file is stored in a string (in the program below it's called sample).

I then have the program extract information from the string based on various formatting rules. This works well, the only issue is that when reading larger files it is very slow....

I was wondering if there was anything I could do to speed up the parsing or if there was an existing library that does what I need (extract string up until a delimiter & extract string string in between 2 delimiters on the same level). Any assistance would be great.

Here's my code & a sample of how it should work...

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string ExtractStringUntilDelimiter(
   std::string& original_string,
   const std::string& delimiter,
   const int delimiters_to_skip = 1)
{
   std::string needle = "";

   if (original_string.find(delimiter) != std::string::npos)
   {
      int total_found = 0;

      auto occurance_index = static_cast<size_t>(-1);

      while (total_found != delimiters_to_skip)
      {
         occurance_index = original_string.find(delimiter);
         if (occurance_index != std::string::npos)
         {
            needle = original_string.substr(0, occurance_index);
            total_found++;
         }
         else
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      // Remove the found string from the original string...
      original_string.erase(0, occurance_index + 1);
   }
   else
   {
      needle = original_string;
      original_string.clear();
   }

   if (!needle.empty() && needle[0] == '\"')
   {
      needle = needle.substr(1);
   }
   if (!needle.empty() && needle[needle.length() - 1] == '\"')
   {
      needle.pop_back();
   }

   return needle;
}

void ExtractInitialDelimiter(
   std::string& original_string,
   const char delimiter)
{
   // Remove extra new line characters
   while (!original_string.empty() && original_string[0] == delimiter)
   {
      original_string.erase(0, 1);
   }
}

void ExtractInitialAndFinalDelimiters(
   std::string& original_string,
   const char delimiter)
{
   ExtractInitialDelimiter(original_string, delimiter);

   while (!original_string.empty() && original_string[original_string.size() - 1] == delimiter)
   {
      original_string.erase(original_string.size() - 1, 1);
   }
}

std::string ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(
   std::string& original_string,
   const std::string& opening_delimiter,
   const std::string& closing_delimiter)
{
   const size_t first_delimiter = original_string.find(opening_delimiter);
   if (first_delimiter != std::string::npos)
   {
      int total_open = 1;
      const size_t opening_index = first_delimiter + opening_delimiter.size();

      for (size_t i = opening_index; i < original_string.size(); i++)
      {
         // Check if we have room for opening_delimiter...
         if (i + opening_delimiter.size() <= original_string.size())
         {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < opening_delimiter.size(); j++)
            {
               if (original_string[i + j] != opening_delimiter[j])
               {
                  break;
               }
               else if (j == opening_delimiter.size() - 1)
               {
                  total_open++;
               }
            }
         }


         // Check if we have room for closing_delimiter...
         if (i + closing_delimiter.size() <= original_string.size())
         {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < closing_delimiter.size(); j++)
            {
               if (original_string[i + j] != closing_delimiter[j])
               {
                  break;
               }
               else if (j == closing_delimiter.size() - 1)
               {
                  total_open--;
               }
            }
         }


         if (total_open == 0)
         {
            // Extract result, and return it...
            std::string needle = original_string.substr(opening_index, i - opening_index);
            original_string.erase(first_delimiter, i + closing_delimiter.size());

            // Remove new line symbols
            ExtractInitialAndFinalDelimiters(needle, '\n');
            ExtractInitialAndFinalDelimiters(original_string, '\n');

            return needle;
         }
      }
   }

   return "";
}

int main()
{
   std::string sample = "{\n"
      "Line1\n"
      "Line2\n"
      "{\n"
         "SubLine1\n"
         "SubLine2\n"
      "}\n"
   "}";

   std::string result = ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(sample, "{", "}");
   std::string LineOne = ExtractStringUntilDelimiter(result, "\n");
   std::string LineTwo = ExtractStringUntilDelimiter(result, "\n");

   std::string SerializedVector = ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(result, "{", "}");
   std::string SubLineOne = ExtractStringUntilDelimiter(SerializedVector, "\n");
   std::string SubLineTwo = ExtractStringUntilDelimiter(SerializedVector, "\n");

   // Just for testing...
   printf("LineOne: %s\n", LineOne.c_str());
   printf("LineTwo: %s\n", LineTwo.c_str());
   printf("\tSubLineOne: %s\n", SubLineOne.c_str());
   printf("\tSubLineTwo: %s\n", SubLineTwo.c_str());
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Did you turn optimizations on when you tested the speed?

Comment: All those calls to `string::erase` will move a lot of data.  Rethink how you're doing what you're doing, so that you don't have to change the original string.  Can you use an index to track what part of the string you're looking at, rather than using the first character?

Answer (score 5):

Use `string_view` or a hand rolled one.

Don't modify the string loaded.

```
  original_string.erase(0, occurance_index + 1);
```

is code smell and going to be expensive with a large original string.

If you are going to modify something, do it in one pass.  Don't repeatedly delete from the front of it -- that is O(n^2).  Instead, procceed along it and shove "finished" stuff into an output accumulator.

This will involve changing how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient version of `ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters`. Note that this version does not mutate the original buffer. You would perform subsequent queries on the returned string.

```
std::string trim(std::string buffer, char what)
{
    auto not_what = [&what](char ch)
    {
        return ch != what;
    };
    auto first = std::find_if(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), not_what);
    auto last = std::find_if(buffer.rbegin(), std::make_reverse_iterator(first), not_what).base();
    return std::string(first, last);
}

    std::string ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(
        std::string const& buffer,
        const char opening_delimiter,
        const char closing_delimiter)
    {
        std::string result;

        auto first = std::find(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), opening_delimiter);
        if (first != buffer.end())
        {
            auto last = std::find(buffer.rbegin(), std::make_reverse_iterator(first),
                                         closing_delimiter).base();
            if(last > first)
            {
                result.assign(first + 1, last);
                result = trim(std::move(result), '\n');
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If you have access to `string_view` (c++17 for std::string_view or boost::string_view) you could return one of these from both functions for extra efficiency.

It's worth mentioning that this method of parsing a structured file is going to cause you problems down the line if any of the serialised strings contains a delimiter, such as a '{'.

In the end you'll want to write or use someone else's parser.

The `boost::spirit` library is a little complicated to learn, but creates very efficient parsers for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're reading your data into a string.  "Length of string" should not be a problem. So far, so good...
2. You're using "string.find().".  That's not necessarily a *bad* choice.
3. You're using "string.erase()".  That's probably the main source of your problem.

SUGGESTIONS:

- Treat the original string as "read-only".  Don't call erase(), don't modify it.
- Personally, I'd consider reading your text into a C string (a text buffer), then parsing the text buffer, using [strstr()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr).

Comment: I wouldn't condone using strstr here. But there is a find overload which takes an initial index, which will be almost as efficient.

Comment: I totally agree with you about considering the [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) overload - great suggestion!  Personally, I have no problem using C functions "just because they're 'C'", but that's a matter of taste and opinion.  A taste C++ bigots would have a very hard time with ;)